# side-by-side same file GUI text editor?

Tags: text-editor

I need to see two parts of the same file. Sometimes I need to edit. Is there a side-by-side same file GUI text editor?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Geany`.

```
sudo apt install geany.
```

Then after running `Geany`, from "Tools" menu select "Plugin Manager" and check "Split Window" to enable this plugin.

[image]

Then click on "split window" to highlight it and click on "keybindings", Assign a key binding to side by side, then using those keys you get your document side by side.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`gvim -O myfile myfile`
opens a GUI text editor window with two side-by-side independently-scrollable views on the same file.

Or if you're already in `gvim myfile`, you can `:vsplit` to get the same thing.